# Is there a non-commercial Hibernate query checker?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, persistence

We are using Hibernate at my workplace on some project and I had to modify some queryes recently. I found it really cumbersome to modify a query, run an `ant smart` or `ant refresh` and see whether my query works. When I asked one of my colleagues he told me that it is the way we use it.

Do you have any idea how can I speed up this process? I'm looking for a tool which can connect to a database (we are using PGSQL) and run my Hibernate query there and show the results without touching ant.

For example I would be able to try this:

```
@Query(query = "SELECT DISTINCT l FROM Line l, IN(l.workplaces) w WHERE w.workshop.sid=:wsid", params = "wsid")
```

Comment: Hibernate is in no way linked to ant. It can be used in any JSE application. You can make such an application yourself very easily.

Comment: I know it is not linked but our application is built using ant. I don't want to run ant every time i want to try a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss Tools for eclipse has a HQL editor that you can open from the hibernate perspective, you can test hql queries there.

Answer (score 1):

We have a junit-Test for hibernate which uses the [derby database](https://db.apache.org/derby/) as a in-memory databse. This will create the database in derby with all tables and you should be able to execute the query, to see if it is valid.

We have all queries in the orm.xml, so those queries are already checked when creating the EntityManager.

### setup

```
  private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
  private static EntityManager em;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void before()
  {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenztest");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
  }
```

### test

```
  @Test public void test()
  {
    Query q = em.createQuery(YOUR_QUERY_HERE);
    List<?> list =  q.getResultList();
  }
```

### Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="persistenztest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:sa;create=true;territory=de_DE;collation=TERRITORY_BASED:SECONDARY;"/>

      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```